# Alternative "spend on something", "amount of money"

Tags: synonyms

For example:

- The company have spent $500 on clothing and books.
- The amount of money we need to pay for these stuffs is around $300.

I'm writing an essay so academic or formal is preferable

Comment: You want formal about _spend_ and _pay_? You're talking about the Commercial Transaction Frame, as described [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf), or [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf), both as introductory material.

Answer (score 0):

*The company have spent $500 on clothing and books* could be written as

> The company *expended* $500 on clothing and books.

*The amount of money we need to pay for these stuffs is around $300* could be written as

> The *budget* for these *items* is *approximately* $300.